# Parent menu link not working when dropdown menu included

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

Why is the parent menu link not working when drop down menu is included even if link is active?
See 'Services' menu link on
http://demo.rjfkramer.com/

This is a wordpress website.

Thanks!

Comment: i coudn't find it right off, but from what i noticed is that certain data-attributes are re-applied when they are deleted (using element inspector). I assume the menu library is taking in consideration for potential Mobile/Tablet users hense it does a preventDefault behavior. This is unlikely a Wordpress problem and more of a theme related issue with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

it's because of the data-toggle attribute, when there is more then one level of links they "parent" (first level link) get the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute so his link href will not be available, you can read about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript#dropdowns

Comment: if you are using JQuery, you can put this line on your js theme code: $('.dropdown-toggle').removeAttr('data-toggle');