# Parent menu is not clickable, Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have meet an issue with parent menu is not clickable. I have tried all possible as well as my own suggestions into it but did not get any luck.

My site is in wordpress [Site](https://www.dev.learn2strut.com/)

I have also tried the custom link and the main menu work when i set menu as standalone which means no submenu.

Kindly check my website and please provide me solution for the same.
There is a error in console as well.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
    at window.particlesJS (particles.js?ver=5.1.1:1495)
    at app.js?ver=5.1.1:14
```

Thank you.

Comment: By seeing the error I can tell that the object which is being referenced for 'getElementsByClassName' is not available at the time of execution. Please post the corresponding script as well.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt according to your comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Thank you @KrishnaPrashatt for revert back this is the script https://www.dev.learn2strut.com/wp-content/themes/rexal/js/particles.js?ver=5.1.1

If i used same menu as standalone it works and in case of adding submenu the links appears but parent menu is not clickable while submenu works fine

Comment: Probably got caught and prevented by `data-toggle="dropdown1"`.

Comment: @josephting thank you for reply i have tried in console to remove it but it still have same issue

Comment: @Nasser i have tried your code but still have same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution. (add this code to your js and make sure class match)

```
jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
 var location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 window.location.href = location;
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping me i got the answer from one of the stackoverflow link now:
[Parent menu link not working when dropdown menu included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833714/parent-menu-link-not-working-when-dropdown-menu-included)

This is the link working fine now.

Comment: Great, go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your code you didn't have any class by the name of `particles-js-canvas-el`
you can try with WordPress parent menu class like this `menu-item-has-children`
Or you can use any valid class name.
try this on line 1492

```
  /* pJS elements */
  var pJS_tag = document.getElementById(tag_id),
      pJS_canvas_class = 'menu-item-has-children',
      exist_canvas = pJS_tag.getElementsByClassName(pJS_canvas_class);
```

Comment: I found this error in my error_log as well
[06-Apr-2019 16:23:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/selinfoo/public_html/dev.learn2strut.com/wp-content/themes/rexal/includes/modules/shortcodes/projects_mix.php on line 72

Comment: @ Nasser i have added your code in same js file but at live server it is not showing the same i have clear my cache as well. Can you please check

Comment: @PardeepPathania you haven't `particles-js` id as well, please check step by step that you have valid data, check the pJS_tag, tag_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191426/discussion-between-pardeep-pathania-and-nasser).